# access JSON results from wordpress database with wpdb

Tags: database, wordpress

I have JSON results from Google API added to to wp_options table. 
At this point I just need to echo the specific elements. Namely, the coordinates.
The option_name I have is py_menu_item.
One of the option_value element is coords. That is what represents the JSON results.
The code below yields this response: `array(o){}`

The code:

```
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT coords FROM $wpdb->wp_options");
$lat = $myrows->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;    //latitude
$long = $myrows->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;   //longitude 
echo $lat;
echo $long;
var_dump($myrows);
```

I am using this Codex page as a guide: [Class_Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Use get_option and it will simplify things a LOT.

```
function test(){
    //Note no need to reference $wpdb global. 
    //My code here is more verbose than needed, but it explains each step.
    $jsonString = get_option('py_menu_item');//get the val from the options table
    $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString);   //decode the JSON serialized string
    $coords = $jsonArray['coords'];          //get reference to the attribute
    var_dump($coords);                       //do what you want with it
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to work. 'coords' has already been decoded if that makes a difference.

Comment: So var_dump your data from get_option() and see where 'coords' is in the array and call it accordingly.

Comment: Btw this line $coords = $jsonArray('coords'); is wrong. It should be $coords = $jsonArray['coords'];